# Asus X554LA fn+brightness problem

Tags: brightness, asus, 15.10

I'm new to ubuntu and my Asus X555LA brought me here.

The `fn` + `(brightness up/brightness down)` is not working, i did some search and what i tried till now is modifying `grub` file from `etc\default`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi_Linux"
```

To mention `fn+brightness` works in BIOS and i use ubuntu 15.10 but the same problem is in 14.04 or 14.10.

Now is there any other solution? And if there is please can you explain it on baby steps :-?

hw:

> -cpu
>
> ```
>       product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5010U CPU @ 2.10GHz
>       vendor: Intel Corp.
>       physical id: 1
>       bus info: cpu@0
>       size: 2100MHz
>       capacity: 2100MHz
>       width: 64 bits
> ```
>
> -display
>
> ```
>          description: VGA compatible controller
>          product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
>          vendor: Intel Corporation
>          physical id: 2
>          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>          version: 09
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>          configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>          resources: irq:48 memory:b1000000-b1ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
> ```

PS: I did found xbacklight app with custom keys, but the fact that fn on brightness doesn't work bugs me.

edit:

ls /sys/class/backlight

asus-nb-wmi intel_backlight

Thanks,
Kim

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `ls /sys/class/backlight`

Comment: Did you try boot parameter `acpi_osi=`? Without any "Linux", etc.

Comment: Yes did that, i found out that my fn and brightness keys are not bound to any event... i did some dig and there's a way to do it but it's to complicated, so first i need to get used with ubuntu then maybe ill try fix that :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: After upgrading to 17.04 this issue no longer occurred.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `xbacklight`, then you need to point the default control to `intel_backlight`.

Run

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

and paste this text to gedit:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Card0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

then reboot.

Comment: Still not working, with this one i can't even modify the brightness from system settings or xbacklight. I did update grub every time...

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: still nothing ... does my grub need to look like this or im doning something wrong ?
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=intel_backlight"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: It is wrong to put this to linux cmdline.

Comment: ok, i changed it back to quiet splash then reboot, and still nothing :-s the fn+brightness is not working. i'm still using normal key bind to use the xbacklight app

Answer (score 0):

I have asus and i had same problem since 15.04
this how i fix it

install latest intel driver from http://01.org/linuxgraphics

then edit grub as below

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= acpi acpi_backlight=vendor
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noprompt persistent"

Comment: i tried it and still not working. the weird part is that there's no event on brightness key's and I think that's the main problem, but i don't know how to link those key to an event

Comment: I tested brightness Fn keys with command acpi_listen and there was no event, after did above steps it's working